# How to copy a Word.Document and paste him in folder path?

Tags: c#, add-in, office-interop

I developed an AddIn for Office 2010. In Word when I launch my AddIn I do a SaveAs(string path). After there is a serveur who make some actions with this. But I have an error like this

> The process cannot access the file
>   '\pc8160\d$\Geode\ExternalData\DRUM\UPLOAD_FILE_FROM_ADDIN\IC_XML_FILE_PROTECTION\FILE\Programming
>   Guide.doc' because it is being used by another process

It's logic because when you do a SaveAs word open the document from the new path and you must the quit the word file. It because I want to copy this word file and not SaveAs. How can I do that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**VSTO** specific functionality is not needed for this. Simply use `File.Copy` found in `System.IO`.

```
File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName, overwrite);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to copy the file don't use the SaveAs method. Instead, you need to use file IO operations - [File.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(v=vs.110).aspx).